# ultrasonic sensor does not match with URDF

Tags: ros, urdf, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have a real robot with 4 diffrent ultrasonic sensors publishing on 4 different topics. I used the same name in my URDF file as publishers however when i want to display it on RVIZ the location is wrong. is there any guidline that i can refer to ? or anyone has idea what i am doing wrong ?

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

This is the topic echo

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ rostopic echo /lSonic

header:
  seq: 4023
  stamp:
    secs: 1615356239
    nsecs: 343081474
  frame_id: "/base_footprint"
radiation_type: 0
field_of_view: 0.25999999046325684
min_range: 0.0
max_range: 7.0
range: 5.357534885406494
---
```

This is the topic info

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ rostopic info /lSonic
Type: sensor_msgs/Range

Publishers:
 * /ultrasonic (http://ubuntu:42959/)

Subscribers:
 * /rviz_1615277321083748871 (http://vm-ubuntu-20:42115/)
```

This is ultrasonic publisher code

```
r = Range()
r.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
r.header.frame_id = "/base_footprint"
r.radiation_type = 0
r.field_of_view = 0.26
r.min_range = 0.0
r.max_range = 7.0
r.range = measurementInCM(GPIO_SIGPIN)/100
publisher.publish(r)
rospy.sleep(1.0)
```

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373606/ultrasonic-sensor-does-not-match-with-urdf/) by [AmirSaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/64433/amirsaman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2021-03-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-09**:
I'm sorry to have to do this for something so seemingly unimportant, but please don't post screenshots of terminal text in question on ROS Answers. It's all text, so there is no need. Just copy-paste the text from the terminal into your question text. Do make sure to format it properly by selecting the text and pressing `ctrl+k` (or clicking the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it)).

You don't need to post a new question, just edit your curent one. You can use the `edit` button/link for this.

After you replace the screenshot with the error message itself, we can re-open your question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-09**:
As to your problem: as stated in the [sensor_msgs/Range](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html) documentation, `min_range`, `max_range` and `range` use units of *metres*.

Does your sensor really have a max range of 350 metres?

It's likely you're populating the fields with data in centimetres.

**Comment by [AmirSaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/64433/amirsaman/) on 2021-03-09**:
@gvdhoom I converted t he values to meter and now i can not see anything on RVIZ

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-09**:
The `max_range` of your sensor is `7.5` cm? That seems really small. Previously (in the screenshots) it was `350` metres (or centimetres, if it was centimetres). Wouldn't that be `3.5` m after conversion instead?

Comparing the screenshots with the `rostopic echo` output you show now, perhaps you divided by `1e3` instead of `1e2`?

And `field_of_view` is `0.10000000149011612` radians? That's only approx `5.7` degrees. Possible of course, but also seems small.

**Comment by [AmirSaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/64433/amirsaman/) on 2021-03-10**:
Thank you for your answer, I already modify the code accordingly now it become better however the location is still wrong. look at the first picture the range should be start from leftside of the robot and look at left not right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the soultion, the problem was in this line

frame_id: "/base_footprint"  I had to remove the "/" and now everything is working fine.

---

Originally posted by [AmirSaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/64433/amirsaman/) with karma: 130 on 2021-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0